# Exclusão da tag "angulajs"

Tags: suporte, tag-específica

Nós temos a tag [angulajs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angulajs). Alguém digitou errado e continuaram a usá-la. Hoje de manhã existiam 6 perguntas com esta tag, eu mudei todas para [angularjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs).

Temos como excluir essa tag?

---

Lista das perguntas com a tag errada:
[Como usar função ng-click do angularjs que retorna de um html do php?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90520/)
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92748/
[Problema com botoes quando clicado no AngularJS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95945/)
[Não consigo chamar uma função com ng-click](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96087/)
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96253/
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95648/